# Firebase observe/query at parent and ignore one of the child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just start using firebase and I have data view like this.

[image]

I observe/query for **con-LD-iQlmxyvo2t3mvwER** like this.

```
private void retrieveConversation(String conversationID) {

    Query queryRoom = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Conversation").child(conversationID);

    queryRoom.keepSynced(true);

    queryRoom.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Conversation conversation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);
            if (conversation != null) {
                conversation = updateConversation(conversation);
                mainMessage.conversations.put(conversation.getId(), conversation);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChatAdapter.AddMessage());
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChatDetailAdapter.ReceiveMessage());

                if (chatDetailBlock != null) {
                    if (conversation.getId().equals(chatDetailID)) {
                            chatDetailBlock.run();
                        chatDetailBlock = null;
                        chatDetailID = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Problem is I need to ignore "**messsages**" child node, listen/observe the rest and update the object (or at least limit the number of messages). Is it possible to do?

Comment: Based on my knowledge it is not possible. Possible thing to do is create a separate node called messages and use the same push Id inside it to add the messages.. If the structure to be like this only inside onDataChange save the values to be checked inside shared preference and check it with each time it triggers

Comment: Why would you like to ignore `messsages` node?